# Terraform AWS Provider Ignoring Profile and Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a root terraform module that specifies multiple providers. Each provider specifies a profile `my-profile` and a role ARN `arn:aws:iam::944367763317:role/superuser`. However, when I run `terraform apply`, I get an error like this for each resource:

> AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/me@my-org.com is not authorized to perform: iam:GetPolicy on resource: policy arn:aws:iam::123456789:policy/my-policy

It is true that this user does not have access to this resource, that's why I told terraform to use the superuser role. From this AccessDenied error I can see that it is not using that role.

I'm using the AWS provider `v5.12`. I also attempted this using the latest `v5.38` and had the same result.

Here's my root module:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source                = "hashicorp/aws"
      version               = "~> 5.12"
      configuration_aliases = [aws.us_west_1, aws.us_west_2]
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.5.5"

  backend "s3" {
    profile      = "my-profile"
    bucket       = "terraform"
    key          = "terraform.tfstate"
    region       = "us-west-2"
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/superuser"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  allowed_account_ids = ["1234566789"]
  region              = "us-west-1"
  alias               = "us_west_1"
  profile             = "my-profile"
  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::1234566789:role/listening-superuser"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  allowed_account_ids = ["987654321"]
  region              = "us-west-2"
  alias               = "us_west_2"
  profile             = "my-profile"
  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::987654321:role/superuser"
  }
}

module "child_module" {
  source = "./child_module"
  providers = {
    aws.us_west_1 = aws.us_west_1
    aws.us_west_2 = aws.us_west_2
  }
}
```

Here are the contents of `child_module.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source                = "hashicorp/aws"
      version               = "~> 5.12"
      configuration_aliases = [aws.us_west_1, aws.us_west_2]
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.5.5"
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "my_user" {
  name = "my-user"
}

...
```

~/.aws/credentials

```
[source-profile]
output=json
region=us-west-1
aws_access_key_id=AK123456789
aws_secret_access_key=abcdefghijklmnop
```

~/.aws/config

```
[profile my-profile]
region=us-west-1
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/superuser
source_profile = source-profile
```

I can confirm via the aws cli that my roles and profiles are configured correctly and have admin permissions for reading and writing. I've tried setting the `AWS_PROFILE` and `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` and neither makes a difference.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: When you pass multiple providers to a child module, make sure one of them is not using an alias.

First, it's important to understand the difference between an aliased and a non-aliased providers. The original terraform configuration above uses only aliased providers:

```
module "child_module" {
  source = "./child_module"
  providers = {
    aws.us_west_1 = aws.us_west_1  # Aliased as "us_west_1" in the child module
    aws.us_west_2 = aws.us_west_2  # Aliased as "us_west_2" in the child module
  }
}
```

Instead you could use a non-aliased provider:

```
module "child_module" {
  source = "./child_module"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.us_west_1  # Not aliased: us_west_1 becomes the default provider
    aws.us_west_2 = aws.us_west_2  # Aliased as "us_west_2" in the child module
  }
}
```

What happens to resources in the child module that don't specify a resource?

`./child_module/child_module.tf`

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "my_user" {
  name = "my-user"
}
```

If there's a non-aliased, default provider, then of course the default provider is used to create `aws_iam_user.my_user`.

If there's no default provider (only multiple aliased providers), then the behavior might be surprising: terraform doesn't use *any* provider, it simply uses the current AWS credentials to modify the resource directly. This can be very confusing if you don't know it's happening.

Fortunately, the solution is simple: make sure that *either* each module has a default provider (preferred) *or* make sure each resource explicitly sets the `provider` arg.